# Rest API with restc-cpp post data assertion error

Tags: c++, json, rest

I'm trying to post json data in C++ with the [restc-cpp](https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp/blob/master/doc/Tutorial.md) library and I have this error:

```
Assertion failed: false, file lib\restc-cpp\include\restc-cpp/SerializeJson.h, line 1273
```

I have followed the examples on this page [Post data to the server](https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp/blob/master/doc/Tutorial.md#post-data-to-the-server)

```
struct Post
{
   int i;
};


// The C++ main function - the place where any adventure starts
int main() {

    Post post;
    post.i = 22;

    // Create an instance of the rest client
    auto rest_client = RestClient::Create();

    // Create and instantiate a Post from data received from the server.
    auto done = rest_client->ProcessWithPromise([&](Context& ctx)
    {
        // This is a co-routine, running in a worker-thread


       auto reply = RequestBuilder(ctx)
                 .Post("http://ptsv2.com/t/ywexb-1620143951/post")

                 .Data(post)
                 // Send the request
                 .Execute();

       cout << "GOT: " << reply->GetBodyAsString() << endl;

    });

    try
    {
    // Get the Post instance from the future<>, or any C++ exception thrown
    // within the lambda.
       done.get();
    }
    catch(const exception& ex)
    {
       cout << "Main thread: Caught exception from coroutine: "
             << ex.what() << endl;
    }
```

The error occurs during the "post" data structure serializing in this below function of "SerializeJson.h" file

```
template <typename dataT, typename serializerT>
void do_serialize(const dataT& object, serializerT& serializer,
                const serialize_properties_t& properties,
    typename std::enable_if<
        !boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence<dataT>::value
        && !std::is_integral<dataT>::value
        && !std::is_floating_point<dataT>::value
        && !std::is_same<dataT, std::string>::value
        && !is_container<dataT>::value
        && !is_map<dataT>::value
        >::type* = 0) {
    assert(false);
};
```

The line 1273 is on the assert.

Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error.
I have read the documentation about [enable_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/?kw=enable_if) in type_traits standard library.
It appears it is a check for integral_type, floating_point, ... in

```
...
typename std::enable_if<
        !boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence<dataT>::value
        && !std::is_integral<dataT>::value
        && !std::is_floating_point<dataT>::value
        && !std::is_same<dataT, std::string>::value
        && !is_container<dataT>::value
        && !is_map<dataT>::value
        >::type* = 0)
...
```

And in my original code I give a Post structure to Data function

```
Post post;
post.i = 22;
...
auto reply = RequestBuilder(ctx)
                 .Post("http://ptsv2.com/t/ywexb-1620143951/post")

                 .Data(post)
                 // Send the request
                 .Execute();
```

I tried directly with a "int" and it is ok.
Then I have read the [restc-cpp doc](https://github.com/jgaa/restc-cpp#fetch-a-c-object-from-a-server-that-serialize-to-json) and added the BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT macro with a string in struct after Post structure definition:

```
struct Post
{
   int i;
   string name;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Post,
    (int, i)
    (string, name)
)
```

And the post request was successfull !

I hope it helps others !